# when error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS occur and how to resolve it?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I have problem when I login in my website -->
chrome display error **ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**.

i want you help me understand:

- what is problem?
- why and when it occur?
- how to resolve it?

I was research in google, it say i should clear cache and problem will resolve but it not true.

**content of log file is below**:

```
INFO: Deployment of web application directory D:\Compressed\apache-tomcat-      7.0.55\webapps\ROOT has finished in 367 ms
Jun 13, 2015 9:05:16 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Jun 13, 2015 9:05:16 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Jun 13, 2015 9:05:16 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 17290 ms
className UserDAO
methodName actionLogIn
pageForward: sessionTimeout.page
className UserDAO
methodName actionLogIn
pageForward: sessionTimeout.page
className UserDAO
methodName actionLogIn
pageForward: sessionTimeout.page
className UserDAO
methodName actionLogIn
pageForward: sessionTimeout.page
className UserDAO
methodName actionLogIn
pageForward: sessionTimeout.page
className UserDAO
methodName actionLogIn
pageForward: sessionTimeout.page
className UserDAO
methodName actionLogIn
pageForward: sessionTimeout.page
className UserDAO
methodName actionLogIn
pageForward: sessionTimeout.page
className UserDAO
methodName actionLogIn
pageForward: sessionTimeout.page
className UserDAO
methodName actionLogIn
pageForward: sessionTimeout.page
className UserDAO
methodName actionLogIn
pageForward: sessionTimeout.page
className UserDAO
methodName actionLogIn
pageForward: sessionTimeout.page
className UserDAO
methodName actionLogIn
pageForward: sessionTimeout.page
className UserDAO
methodName actionLogIn
pageForward: sessionTimeout.page
```

Comment: guessing your page is forwarding to itself

Comment: I'd guess that you have a "must be logged in" requirement applied to your login endpoint.

Comment: Agreed, you're linking to yourself somehow. Let's see the code of the page(s) and maybe we can find it.

Comment: You should post some lines of code.